# Create linked tables in access with vba

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I'm working with a database in Access 2007, one front end and a few backends.

I like to convert all my linked tables to local for offline work so that i don't accidentally spoil the data.

I delete all the relations and tables and then run a saved import.

I'd like to recreate linked tables after I'm done with modifications. Problem is, Access won't save the import of linked tables. Is there a way to simply link all the tables from backend to frontend with VBA

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the net that works, though slow

```
Function createAttached(strTable As String, strPath As String, strBaseTable As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo CreateAttachedError

Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim strConnect As String
Dim fRetval As Boolean
Dim myDB As Database

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    Set myDB = CurrentDb
    Set tdf = myDB.CreateTableDef(strTable)

    With tdf
        .Connect = ";DATABASE=" & strPath
        .SourceTableName = strBaseTable
    End With

    myDB.TableDefs.Append tdf

    fRetval = True

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

CreateAttachedExit:
    createAttached = fRetval
    Exit Function

CreateAttachedError:
    If Err = 3110 Then
        Resume CreateAttachedExit
    Else
        If Err = 3011 Then
            Resume Next
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

https://www.microsoftaccessexpert.com/Microsoft-Access-Code-LinkTable.aspx